# FreeBSD issue a system call from another system call

Tags: kernel, hook, freebsd

I wrote some freebsd kernel modules like 1 year ago, they were working fine at that time. But now I can't compile.

What I'm trying to do is to hook an existing system call by modifying sysent table.

```
static int
mkdir_hook (struct proc *p, struct mkdir_args *ua)
{
 printf("Making dir:  %s\n", ua->path);
 return mkdir(p, ua);
}

static int
load (struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg)
{
 int error = 0;

 switch (cmd) {
   case MOD_LOAD :
      sysent[SYS_mkdir]=mkdir_hook_sysent;
      break;
   case MOD_UNLOAD :
      sysent[SYS_mkdir].sy_call=(sy_call_t*)mkdir;
      break;
   default :
      error = EINVAL;
      break;
  }
 return error;
}
```

I get the following error

```
test.c:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mkdir'
test.c:21: warning: nested extern declaration of 'mkdir' [-Wnested-externs]
test.c:49: error: 'mkdir' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:49: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:49: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

So I think it might be missing library. Here's my include

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/linker.h>
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
```

I read `man 2 mkdir`, still no clue. It seems that calling another system call from within a kernel module is no longer supported or it requires additional configuration?

Please help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system call entry is now prefixed with "sys_" so you should use sys_mkdir instead of just mkdir now.

The exact changeset was:

> r225617 | kmacy | 2011-09-16 06:58:51 -0700 (Fri, 16 Sep 2011) | 12 lines
>
> In order to maximize the re-usability of kernel code in user space this
>   patch modifies makesyscalls.sh to prefix all of the non-compatibility
>   calls (e.g. not linux_, freebsd32_) with sys_ and updates the kernel
>   entry points and all places in the code that use them. It also
>   fixes an additional name space collision between the kernel function
>   psignal and the libc function of the same name by renaming the kernel
>   psignal kern_psignal(). By introducing this change now we will ease future
>   MFCs that change syscalls.

Comment: found it in /usr/src/sys/sys/sysent.h, 
        '"sys/" #name,' tyvm