# How to solve this compiler error

Tags: c, kernel, freebsd, kernel-module

Experimenting with some FreeBSD kernel hacking and I ran into an error on a simple hook example. The code is as follows

*NOTE - I have added `#include <sys/stat.h>` as many have suggested, but continue to get the same error.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static int mkdir_hook(struct thread *td, void *syscall_args) {

  struct mkdir_args *uap;
  uap = (struct mkdir_args *)syscall_args;
  char path[255];
  size_t done;
  int error;
  error = copyinstr(uap->path, path, 255, &done);
  if(error != 0)
    return (error);

  uprintf("hooked it\n");
  return (mkdir(td, syscall_args));
}

static int load(struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg) {
  int error = 0;
  switch(cmd){
  case MOD_LOAD:
    sysent[SYS_mkdir].sy_call = (sy_call_t *)mkdir_hook;
    break;
  case MOD_UNLOAD:
    sysent[SYS_mkdir].sy_call = (sy_call_t *)mkdir;
    break;
  default:
    error = EOPNOTSUPP;
    break;
  }
  return(error);
}

static moduledata_t mkdir_hook_mod = {
  "mkdir_hook",
  load,
  NULL
};

DECLARE_MODULE(mkdir_hook, mkdir_hook_mod, SI_SUB_DRIVERS, SI_ORDER_MIDDLE);
```

The compiler error is

```
    mkdirhook.c:23:11: error: implicit declaration of function 'mkdir' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  return (mkdir(td, syscall_args));
          ^
1 error generated.
*** Error code 1
```

My guess is this is a simple problem and the code sample I'm using is out of date.

Comment: include [`sys/stat.h.`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-Directories.html)

Comment: It's scary to think you are attempting to hack an OS kernel.

Comment: @RSahu - I'm not malicious or something; Its just a fun way to learn stuff.

Comment: @Roge Kernel programming is very different from user-space programming. For starters, there is no `libc` (see my answer below). You should start with reading the intro(9) manual page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `mkdir` in a kernel module.

The `mkdir` function is part of the standard C library (`libc`) which can only be used in *user-space programs*, not in kernel or module code!

So the definition of `mkdir` in  `sys/stat.h` is in an `#ifndef _KERNEL/#endif` block and won't be "seen" if you are compiling a kernel module.

In 2011, all system calls were all given a `sys_` prefix. (See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017403/freebsd-issue-a-system-call-from-another-system-call)) So you should use `sys_mkdir` instead.

Comment: Was it possible in the past to use libc in FreeBSD kernel modules ? I was planning to follow the book by Joseph King "Designing BSD Rootkits - an introduction to kernel hacking" but all his sample code is using libc functions in kernel modules.

Comment: As far as I know, it was never possible. But sometimes a similarly named function is available in kernel mode. E.g. `malloc(9)`. The book that you mention is now seven years old. I think it is somewhat out of date. E.g. the `mkdir` that he's using is probably named `sys_mkdir` now.

Comment: @Roge System calls were renamed in 2011 to prevent confusion. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the case - makes it a bit trickier but I can probably navigate now knowing what the problem was. Thanks for the thorough info

Answer (score 3):

mkdir() is defined in sys/stat.h on FreeBSD.  The code need to:

```
  #include <sys/stat.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include sys/stat.h to use the mkdir function.

`#include <sys/stat.h>`

Answer (score 1):

`implicit declaration of function 'mkdir'` is the give-away... you're trying to use a function  (`mkdir()`)  that has not been prototyped.
Prototype it: `#include <sys/stat.h>`